# How to convert time from hh:mm:ss.mmm to seconds and milliseconds mysql

Tags: mysql, time, milliseconds, seconds, datetime-conversion

I would like to convert all values in a column from "hh:mm:ss.mmm" to "ss.mmm". 
I have tried `TIME_FORMAT(`Duration`, 's%.f%)` but this shows the seconds and milliseconds and doesn't keep calculate the correct seconds when values are over 1 minute.

Alternatively I could use the difference between the start and end columns, as long as it returned the time in "ss.mmm". I have tried this using `TIMESTAMPDIFF(microsecond,`Start`,`End`)as diff` but it is to milliseconds and I don't know how to convert it to "ss.mmm". And when specifying second instead of microsecond it loses the milliseconds.

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you saying that `12:35:15.293` becomes just `15.293`?  Why would you want to do this?  Or, do you want report the original amount as just numbers of seconds and milliseconds?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think OP wants to convert hours and minutes to seconds also and show everything as seconds.microseconds

Comment: Use `TIME_TO_SEC()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you're asking, if I understand correctly you already have the data containing milliseconds.

I don't think MySQL has an inherent millisecond function, but we can use microseconds instead.

```
SELECT CONCAT(TIME_TO_SEC('15:30:15.293'), '.', TIME_FORMAT('15:30:15.293', '%f'));
```

This will output as below;

```
55815.293000
```